# Optimize Recursive Fetching of information?

Tags: c#, recursion

I wrote a small class that demonstrates my problem:

```
class Root
{
    private Leaf RootLeaf;
    private Dictionary<object, Leaf> AllItems = new Dictionary<object, Leaf>();  //dictionary contains a reference to each item, and the leaf it is assigned to (its parent)
    public Root()
    {
        RootLeaf = new Leaf();
    }

    public List<object> GetAllChildren
    {
        get { return RootLeaf.getAllChildren; }
    }

    public void Add(object o)
    {
        Leaf AddedTo = RootLeaf.Add(o);
        AllItems.Add(o, AddedTo); //Add object reference to AllItems dictionary
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> GetNeighbors(object obj)
    {
        foreach (object o in this.AllItems[obj].getAllChildren)
        {
            if (obj != o)
                yield return o;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, Leaf> i in AllItems)
        {
            foreach (object b in this.GetNeighbors(i.Key))
            {
                //Would do collision checks here
            }
        }
    }
}

class Leaf
{
    private const int MaxChildCount = 1;

    private List<object> Children = new List<object>();

    private Leaf[] ChildLeaves = null;
    private bool _LeavesGenerated = false; //Have the leaves been created? (Low Level, do not touch)
    private bool HasLeaves = false; //Should we use the leaves?

    protected void CreateLeaves()
    {
        if (!_LeavesGenerated)
        {
            //create each of the four leaves
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                ChildLeaves[i] = new Leaf();
            _LeavesGenerated = true;
        }
        HasLeaves = true;
    }
    protected void RemoveLeaves()
    {
        HasLeaves = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns children of this leaf, and all of its subleaves
    /// </summary>
    public List<object> getAllChildren
    {
        get
        {
            List<object> outp = Children.ToList();
            if (HasLeaves)
            {
                foreach (Leaf l in ChildLeaves)
                    outp.AddRange(l.getAllChildren);
            }
            return outp;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get count of all children in this leaf, and its subleaves
    /// </summary>
    public int getChildCount
    {
        get
        {
            int outp = Children.Count;
            if (HasLeaves)
            {
                foreach (Leaf l in ChildLeaves)
                    outp += l.getChildCount;
            }
            return outp;
        }
    }

    static Random rand = new Random();
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">The object to be added</param>
    /// <returns>The leaf the object was added to</returns>
    public Leaf Add(object o)
    {
        if (Children.Count >= MaxChildCount)
        {
            //Pick random subleaf, I know this isn't correct for a quadtree, but it will simplify this explanation code
            if (!HasLeaves)
                CreateLeaves();
            return ChildLeaves[rand.Next(0, 3)].Add(o);
        }
        else
        {
            Children.Add(o);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this through the ANTS profiler, and it not surprisingly pulled the `Leaf.getAllChildren` and `Leaf.getChildCount` as the two most expensive operations.  I'm ok with how everything thing else is laid out.  My question is: how could I optimize the two aforementioned properties?

The properties are called when the `Root.Update()` function is run.

Comment: What is your test program that uses these classes that you're using to profile?

Comment: I can post it if you feel it's relevent, but it's some 300+ lines, and after optimizing most of it, the profiler pointed out the lines that called the above properties (and the call count can't be reduced) as taking up 30% of the execution time. I'll see if I can trim it down to the important bits.

Comment: Update, I've added what I think you were referring to, was that what you were talking about?

Comment: I don't think so?  I'm looking for perhaps a `Main()` method which creates these objects and calls their methods.

Comment: Oh, they are very simple functions, the first is on form.load and adds new objects, and the second runs on a  every 1000/60 millisecs. I can also add that if you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I've done a bit of work here (a good most of it stylistic, to be sure).  Do note I replaced `object` with a generic implementation to help avoid boxing of value types.  It does also employ LINQ in a couple instances to remove some complexity.  When I run it and generate 1,000,000 integer leaves, I find that the bulk of the time is taken in the class constructors and the methods themselves are close enough to 0 time to be considered 0.  Hope this helps:

```
internal sealed class Root<T>
{
    private readonly Leaf<T> rootLeaf = new Leaf<T>();

    // dictionary contains a reference to each item, and the leaf it is assigned to (its parent)
    private readonly IDictionary<T, Leaf<T>> allItems = new Dictionary<T, Leaf<T>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets GetAllChildren.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<T> GetAllChildren
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rootLeaf.GetAllChildren;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T o)
    {
        var addedTo = this.rootLeaf.Add(o);

        this.allItems.Add(o, addedTo); // Add object reference to AllItems dictionary
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var i in from i in this.allItems from b in this.GetNeighbors(i.Key) select i)
        {
            // Would do collision checks here
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetNeighbors(T obj)
    {
        return this.allItems[obj].GetAllChildren.Where(o => ReferenceEquals(obj, o));
    }
}

internal class Leaf<T>
{
    private const int MaxChildCount = 1;

    private static readonly Random rand = new Random();

    private readonly IList<T> children = new List<T>();

    private List<Leaf<T>> childLeaves;

    private bool hasLeaves; // Should we use the leaves?

    private bool leavesGenerated; // Have the leaves been created? (Low Level, do not touch)

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns children of this leaf, and all of its subleaves
    /// </summary>
    public IList<T> GetAllChildren
    {
        get
        {
            var allChildren = this.children.ToList();

            if (this.hasLeaves)
            {
                this.childLeaves.ToList().ForEach(l => allChildren.AddRange(l.GetAllChildren));
            }

            return allChildren;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get count of all children in this leaf, and its subleaves
    /// </summary>
    public int GetChildCount
    {
        get
        {
            var allChildrenCount = this.children.Count;

            if (this.hasLeaves)
            {
                allChildrenCount += this.childLeaves.Sum(l => l.GetChildCount);
            }

            return allChildrenCount;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o">The object to be added</param>
    /// <returns>The leaf the object was added to</returns>
    public Leaf<T> Add(T o)
    {
        if (this.children.Count < MaxChildCount)
        {
            this.children.Add(o);
            return this;
        }

        // Pick random subleaf, I know this isn't correct for a quadtree, but it will simplify this explanation code
        if (!this.hasLeaves)
        {
            this.CreateLeaves();
        }

        return this.childLeaves[rand.Next(0, 3)].Add(o);
    }

    protected void CreateLeaves()
    {
        if (!this.leavesGenerated)
        {
            // create each of the four leaves
            this.childLeaves = new List<Leaf<T>> { new Leaf<T>(), new Leaf<T>(), new Leaf<T>(), new Leaf<T>() };

            this.leavesGenerated = true;
        }

        this.hasLeaves = true;
    }

    protected void RemoveLeaves()
    {
        this.hasLeaves = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work. Only one thing, can `outp` get a better name?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: One question I can't seem to figure out: How would I select both items in the collision foreach loop?  If I wanted to do something like : `if (Rect1.Intersects(Rect2))` where Rect1 was the first object, and Rect2 was its neighbor? With the nested foreach loops it was simple, take the outer variable, and the inner variable; I'm not sure how to do it with your LINQ though

Comment: Also, would it be better to loop through each child every time I need that information, or should I store it in each leaf (like I do in the Root class), and just update it whenever a child changes leaves?

Answer (score 1):

What I saw when quickly looking at it:

Naming convetion: Some of your Properties and variables are lowerCamelCase, some are UpperCamelCase, some of your variables have a leading underscore, some don't. Some `objects` are called `o`, some `obj`.

Here are [the basic naming conventions proposed for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

- Variables are lowerCamelCase: `myVariable`
- Properties are UpperCamelCase: `MyProperty`
- Methods and Functions are UpperCamelCase: `MyFunction`

Stick to those, and don't confuse them with the Java conventions, they're quite different.

---

```
private Dictionary<object, Leaf> AllItems = new Dictionary<object, Leaf>();  //dictionary contains a reference... ... ...
```

We've got some cool documentation features available, make that information easily accessible:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains a reference to each item, and the leaf it is assigned to (its parent).
/// </summary>
private Dictionary<object, Leaf> AllItems = new Dictionary<object, Leaf>();
```

---

Organize your classes better, what does that lone static Random do there between the `Add` and `getChildCount` functions?

```
static Random rand = new Random();
```

---

You never initialize the `ChildLeaves` variable as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the case information, I do need to follow that more closely. As for the underscore, I use it when I feel it is a low level type of function/variable, and it should never be called straight out, though that probably isn't the best way todo it...